# What's the difference between tf.random.normal and tf.distributions.Normal?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

What's the difference between `tf.random.normal` and `tf.distributions.Normal`?  Or the difference between `tf.distributions.Multinomial` and `tf.random.multinomial` or anything similar?

Is `tf.distributions.Normal` used as the backend for `tf.random.normal`?

Comment: These distributions are now moved to tf probability(https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions). From my understanding, tfp.distributions.Normal will create a probability density for you, from which you can sample, compute log prob, etc. While tf.random.normal will return a tensor sampled from a Normal distribution. So it is just one value and not the complete distribution.

Answer (score 2):

I recently looked at `tf probability`, the new place for `tf distributions`. This is my understanding:

They are not the same. `tf.distributions.Normal` will give you a distribution object from which you can sample (this will be same as evaluating the tensor returned by `tf.random.normal` function call for the same mean and loc values). But, a distribution additionally allows you to evaluate probability of a sample that you provide and all the aspects of having access to a distribution.

For example, you could do the following:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> dist = tf.distributions.Normal(loc=0., scale=1.)
>>> dist.log_prob(tf.random.normal(shape=(3,3)))
<tf.Tensor: id=58, shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.9486696 , -0.95645994, -1.1610177 ],
       [-1.244764  , -1.416851  , -1.1236244 ],
       [-0.9292835 , -0.98901427, -0.9705758 ]], dtype=float32)>
```